# Using arrays and volatile

Tags: parameter-passing, avr, volatile

I have an array.
I am using it from a main program.
I am using it from an ISR.
Do I have to always define it as volatile?
What optimization can compiler apply to my array?

Answer (score 2):

If you declare an `int`, and then read it twice, the compiler can 'remember' the first read and not bother to read it again.

```
static int value = 0;

void ISR() {
    ++value;
} // ISR()

int main() {
    while (value==0) {
       // Do nothing
    } // while
} // main()
```

The compiler could read `value` once, and then test it over and over again, always as zero! The ISR changes it, but the compiler doesn't "see" that change.

If you mark `value` as `volatile`, then the compiler will always read it: it will never remember it:

```
static volatile int value = 0;
```

It doesn't matter if it is an array: the same problem could happen.

```
static volatile int array[256];
```

Comment: Thanks. I know it. I wondered only arrays. If you say "does not matter" I will use "volatile".